# c#: Абстрактный класс с реализациями в виде синглтона. Как запретить иметь публичный конструктор?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Пишу скрипт для компьютерной игры, поэтому не кидайтесь камнями за возможную некоторую нелепость. Никак не могу справиться с задачей. Необходимо реализовать систему прослушки каналов. Каждому каналу соответствует частота вещания в формате string. Каналы необходимо стакать в List. Прослушка осуществляется путем пребора листа и проверки висит ли на канале сообщение. То есть выглядеть это должно примерно так:

```
// global
public static List<Channel> MyChannels = new List<Channel>();

// Где то в конструкторе скрипта
FirstChannel.GetInstance();   // При вызове метода GetInstance() при отсутствии экземпляра класса
SecondChannel.GetInstance();  // созданный объект автоматически записывается в лист MyChannels.

...

// В методе Main()
foreach (Channel channel in MyChannels)
{
    if (channel is FirstChannel)
    {
        // todo

        continue;
    }
}
```

Класс Channel должен быть абстрактным и определять наследников, которые обязательно должны быть реализованы синглтоном. Нужно это для того, чтоб не существовало двух экземпляров одного класса канала, ибо добавляться в лист они будут при создании внутри класса. И если экземпляра будет два, то одно и то же сообщение обработается дважды. Проблема в синтаксисе языка. Моего знания C# хватило только на это:

```
public abstract class Channel
{
    protected Channel instance = null;

    protected abstract string GetWave();

    public abstract Channel GetInstance();
}

public class FirstChannel : Channel
{
    // Родитель не запрещает публичный иметь конструктор, а нужно

    protected override string GetWave()
    {
        return MyConfig.FirstChannelWave;
    }

    public override Channel GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new FirstChannel();

            MyChannels.Add(instance);
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что при такой реализации дочернему элементу класса Channel никак не запрещено иметь свой конструктор, а значит идея не реализована. Всё упирается в то, что как-то необходимо запретить дочернему классу иметь конструктор. Я не нашел адекватных способов как это сделать, однако я далеко не спец в С#, поэтому подозреваю, что это возможно. Надеюсь, здесь есть знатоки, которые помогут мне с решением))

Comment: `instance = new FirstChannel();` - ? A нe `instance = new MainChannel() as Channel;`

Comment: First, конечно же. Недоглядел пока перебивал)

Comment: `instance = new FirstChannel();// as Channel;` - зачем этот cast?

Comment: Он не нужен. Забыл про него. Спасибо. Поправил

Comment: Вот это `public static List<Channel> MyChannels = new List<Channel>();` где хранится?

Comment: В классе Program.

В нем Main(), в нем же прописываются представленные классы.